# NPE Hibernate Cache and org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.initializeFromCache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting a NPE on a Model called IssueStepFieldTypeModel
at

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int hash = 5;
    return 53 * hash + getCode().hashCode();
}
```

getCode() is null even though code is annotated @NotNull
and the instance is indeed in the database with all its data.

the error is being thrown in the call to getIssueStepFieldTypeById.
in the web app the user is requesting to display the model so the query
really can't fail.

this error occured after adding the following line to hibernate.cfg.xml

```
  < class-cache class="hae.op.issu.server.model.IssueStepFieldTypeModel" include="all" usage="read-write" />
```

remove the line and all is well.
the error is happening both my local instance of tomcat 
(which is single user)
and on the development server with a load balancer

FieldType has a reference to its 'owner' StepType

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ISSUETYPE_STEP_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@NotNull
private IssueStepTypeModel issueStepType;
```

StepType has a Set of the FieldTypes it 'owns'

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "issueStepType")
private Set<IssueStepFieldTypeModel> issueStepFieldTypes;
```

abreviated stack trace follows

any assistance would be greatly appreciated

thank you

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at hae.op.issu.server.model.IssueStepFieldTypeModel.hashCode(IssueStepFieldTypeModel.java:128)
 at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:362) 
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:492) 
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217) 
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.initializeFromCache(PersistentSet.java:149)
 at org.hibernate.cache.entry.CollectionCacheEntry.assemble(CollectionCacheEntry.java:58)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.initializeCollectionFromCache(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:159)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:71)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1853) 
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:479)
 at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:899)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.assembleCacheEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:689)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:604)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:459)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
.....................................
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy746.find(Unknown Source) 
at hae.cf.srv.jpa.AbstractDao.findById(AbstractDao.java:56) 
at hae.op.issu.server.dao.IssueStepFieldTypeDaoJpa.findById(IssueStepFieldTypeDaoJpa.java:12)

...................

 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy760.findById(Unknown Source) 
at hae.op.issu.server.service.IssueStepFieldTypeServiceImpl.getIssueStepFieldTypeById(IssueStepFieldTypeServiceImpl.java:47) 
.................................
```

Comment: yes, but is it null before being pulled back from the DB? i.e your persistence implementation creates an object and it is cached before loading all fields, hence the hashCode should cater for it (e.g by assigning a default 'code'). It's a guess

Comment: at point of creation, and before the call to persist, the code field is guaranteed not null and unique